# MySQL - Using field value in another field value when inserting

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert

I am wanting to use a value from one field (which auto incremiments) in the value of another field when insert a new row.

When inserting a new row the product ID is generated automatically, but I want to use that product ID in another field which generates a HTML link dynamically.

For example

**ID | LINK**

1  | products.php?id=*

(the products.php?id=* would obviously be wrapped in html 'a' tags)

I want the ID value to be where the * is shown when inserted.

Is there a way to do this so the process is not manual?

Comment: Try with this: mysqli_insert_id --> http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html)

```
delimiter //

    CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON products
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.link = CONCAT(NEW.link, NEW.id);
    END;//

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like not best idea to have this solution. Are you sure the links will be always this format? Are you sure they will never need additional parameters (ie group id)? 
What you try do do is to store actually the same data in two different formats (one is id and another is unique href).

It will lead to other problems like data inconsistency (ie. a bugy software might create rows with id=123 and link as 'products.php?id=666' - see - there is nothing from database perspective that would protect protect you from having an update statement being called on you records that could corrupt data consistency.

Now generally speaking: make sure there is one source of true for your ID and you always reference to this source of true to dynamically generate other data that relays in this ID.
So in you example I would recommend to have a function that would generate the link dynamically based on ID retried from database. Ie different frameworks have build in methods to do that for you (either groovy, spring, I bet there are PHP frameworks as well), you could write your own simple function as well that would generate the link (ie like this pseud-code:

```
getProductLink (int id) { printf ("product.php?id=%d",id) ;}
```

Having done it this way you will not need to change anything data in database if you decided to change you url structure (And you will ;) ).
PS: If you realy wanted to get the list from database please write an mysql function that will generate the link for you dynamically based on provided ID.

with all good will to spear you a lot of pain in the future